# Flip the bits in C

Tags: c, arrays

Recently in a interview i was asked the below question and i couldn't able to answer it correctly. Can some one please let me know what exactly the answer is.
Question:
You are given an array of size N. The elements of the array are d[0],d[1]...d[N-1] where each d[i] is either 0 or 1. You can perform at most one move on the array :choose any two integers [L,R] and flip all the elements between (and including) the Lth and Rth bits. L and R represent the left most and the right most index of the bits marking the boundaries of the segment which you have decided to flip.

What is the maximum number if 1 - bits (indicated by S) which you can obtain in the final bit string? 'Flipping ' a bit means , that a 0 is transformed to a 1 and a 1 is transformed to a 0.

sample input
8
10010010

sample output
6

Comment: I think the best will be to prepare to a similar *interview* by trying *something* by yourself.

Comment: The question looks incomplete.

Comment: I don't know who upvoted this, but the question is clearly against the community guidelines: bad formatting, incomplete text, no sign of personal research before asking. -1

Comment: I couldn't able to find the exact solution thats is the reason i haven't displayed the code.

Comment: There is no exact solution because you have no limit on N.

Comment: Martin, as I read it now (including the added final paragraph), there *is* an exact solution although I don't see a path other than brute force off the top of my head: find the contiguous run, of any length, with the greatest imbalance of 0s vs 1s in it. Flip that segment and it will give you more extra 1s than flipping any other segment.

Comment: Looking at the solutions posted below, these look more complicated than would be tackled in a normal interview...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete solution to the OP's revised question: I've written it in Python 2.7 rather than C because:

1. This is an algorithmic question, and the language-specific details are relatively unimportant.
2. Python has a really nice [`bitstring` module](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/) for manipulation of arbitrary-length bit-strings.
3. I don't want to do the OP's homework totally for him.

This algorithm is `O(N^2)`: it's the brute-force approach I suggested in [my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069083#comment40846523_26069083). It simply looks at all the substrings of the original string, and finds the one which has the greatest imbalance of 0s and 1s (maximum N_0 - N_1). It uses a half-open definition of the interval `[L,R)` since this is the most natural notation with Python's slicing syntax.

```
import bitstring

def maximize_ones(s):
    best = lbest = rbest = 0
    for ledge in range(0,len(s)-1):
        for redge in range(ledge+1,len(s)):
            if redge-ledge<=best:
                continue

            value = s[ledge:redge].count(0)-s[ledge:redge].count(1)
            if value>best:
                best = value
                lbest = ledge
                rbest = redge
                # Uncomment to show intermediate best-so-far solutions
                # print "Flipping bits [%d,%d) will add %d additional 1s" % (lbest, rbest, best)
    return best, lbest, rbest

s = bitstring.Bits(bin=raw_input("Bit string:"))
d = len(s)

best, lbest, rbest = maximize_ones(s)
best_mask = bitstring.Bits(bin=('0'*lbest)+('1'*(rbest-lbest))+('0'*(len(s)-rbest)))

print "Flipping bits [%d,%d) will add %d additional 1s" % (lbest, rbest, best)
print "   s_orig = %s (contains %d ones)" % (s.bin, s.count(1))
print "   s_flip = %s (contains %d ones)" % ((s^best_mask).bin, (s^best_mask).count(1))
```

Example output:

```
$ python maximize_ones.py
Bit string:101100101001000010100010
Flipping bits [4,22) will add 8 additional 1s
   s_orig = 101100101001000010100010 (contains 9 ones)
   s_flip = 101111010110111101011110 (contains 17 ones)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this? I'm assuming that the definition of [L,R] is inclusive, so that if L=5 and R=2, you want to flip bits 2-5, inclusive.

Basically, you construct a mask which has 1's in the positions to be flipped, and then XOR it with the original integer.

```
int d = 0xdeadbeef; /* 0b11011110101011011011111011101111 */
int l = 5;
int r = 2;
int mask = 0;

for (int ii=r; ii<=l; i++) {
    mask |= 1<<ii;
}

printf("Original: %x", d);
printf("Bits %d-%d flipped: %x", r, l, d^mask) /* 0b11011110101011011011111011010011 */
```

Comment: What if the array is 2049 bits long?

Comment: @MartinJames, is that a real question? You could simply segment the array into `sizeof(int)` chunks and construct the mask and do the XOR-ing word-by-word... that would probably be the most efficient approach.

Comment: This seems to completely miss the point of the original question. The original question is about finding the positions of the bits to flip, given that you must flip every bit in a single contiguous range. This seems to be entirely about the mechanics of flipping bits after you've been given the correct positions.

Comment: @jerrycoffin, my solution *does* flip the bits in a contiguous range, using a bit mask and XOR. Why would the OP have accepted it if I had missed the point?

Comment: ..because it's a homework question and the OP knows no better?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the issue here. Are you saying that (a) the OP didn't understand what he was asking, (b) I didn't understand what I was answering, or (c) I shouldn't have given a sketch of a partial solution knowing that it was a likely homework question? Or something else?

Comment: At least as I read it (whether the OP realizes it or not) the real question is less about "how do I flip bits" (which this would answer) and mostly about "how do I figure out which range of bits to flip to get the maximum number of 1 bits in the result?"

Comment: Jerry, you're right. It looks like the OP has edited the question since I answered it to add this second part clarifying the goal of the problem.

Comment: @DanLenski, I would say you answered the original question just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
I did it C Language:

int elementsCount = 0;
printf("Specify number of elements in arry:\n");
scanf("%d",&elementsCount);
int arrayValue [elementsCount];
printf("Enter elementsCount numbers:\n");
for(int i=0;i<elementsCount;++i)
{
scanf("%d",&arrayValue[i]);
}
printf("Given Elements of Array are :\n");
for(int j=0;j<elementsCount;++j)
{
printf("%d",arrayValue[j]);
}  
printf("\n");
int lValue,rValue;
int count = sizeof(arrayValue)/sizeof(arrayValue[0]);
int onesCount = 0;
printf("Specify LeftIndex Range :\n");
scanf("%d",&lValue);
printf("Specify LeftIndex Range :\n");
scanf("%d", &rValue);   
for (int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
if (i >=lValue && i<=rValue)
{
            int flipValue = arrayValue[i];
            if (flipValue == 0)
            {
                arrayValue[i] = 1;
            }
            else if(flipValue == 1)
            {
                arrayValue[i] = 0;
            }
        }

    }

    for (int k =0;k<count; k++)
    {
        printf("%d",arrayValue[k]);
        if (arrayValue[k] == 1)
        {
            onesCount = onesCount + 1;
        }

    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Total Number of 1's are: %d\n",onesCount);
```

Comment: This accomplishes the mechanical part of the bit-flipping, but it doesn't address the optimization part of the problem which you added in your final paragraph: "What is the maximum number of 1-bits which you can obtain in the final bit string, [by flipping a contiguous subset of the original string]?"